# Objective : Currently we are using maven 2.2.2 version but we suppose to use 3.x version

Tags: maven

Currently, we are using Maven 2.2.2 version but we suppose to use 3.x version when  i am trying with a different version of Maven its showing error like build is failing

Comment: Thank you for your first post at StackOverflow, can you add details of the errors you are facing? This will help people to answer your question faster...

Comment: Really using such an old version ([about 10 Years](https://maven.apache.org/docs/history.html)..it's really time...and of course many things are missing like show the errors your have ? Pom files etc. What you have tried to so far ? etc.